# Java8 Lists return element or null

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream, option-type

I have this piece of code, where I want to return an element if present, otherwise null

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add("Test");
myList.add("Example");
myList.add("Sth");

String str = myList.stream()
            .filter(x -> x.equals("eee"))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseGet(null);
```

but I got an Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException anyway

Comment: Use orElse instead of orElseGet

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`orElseGet` takes a supplier. You want to use `orElse`:

```
.findFirst().orElse(null);
```

It doesn't make much sense to use a supplier to return null, but if you were to, it would look like:

```
.findFirst().orElseGet(() -> null); //if argument is null, you get the NPE
```

The JavaDocs of `orElseGet` (thanks to bambam's comment for the addition) mention it:

> **Throws**:
>  **NullPointerException** - if value is not present and other is null

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add("Test");
myList.add("Example");
myList.add("Sth");

String str = myList.stream()
        .filter(s -> null != s && s.equals("Test"))
        .findFirst()
        .orElseGet(() -> null);
System.out.println(str);
```